# If $f\in L^1(\mu)$ and $\int \limits_{E}fd\mu=0$ for every $E\in \mathfrak{M}$. Then $f=0$ a.e. on $X$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f\in L^1(\mu)$ and $\int \limits_{E}fd\mu=0$ for every $E\in \mathfrak{M}$. Then $f=0$ a.e. on $X$.

**Proof:** First we assume that our function $f$ is real. We have to show that the set $\{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\}$ have zero $\mu$-measure. But $$\{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\}=\{x\in X: f(x)<0\}\cup \{x\in X: f(x)>0\}=B\cup A.$$
Let's take a look at the set $A=f^{-1}((0,\infty])\in \mathfrak{M}$ since $f$-measurable and $(0,\infty]$ is open set.

**Remark:** Suppose that $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ is measurable, $E\in \mathfrak{M}$, and $\int \limits_{E}fd\mu=0$. Then $f=0$ a.e. on $E$.

Let $A_1=\{x\in X: f(x)\geqslant 0\}=f^{-1}([0,+\infty])\in \mathfrak{M}$. By aasumption $\int \limits_{A_1}fd\mu=0$ and using ramrk we get that $f=0$ a.e. on $A_1$, i.e. $\mu(\{x\in A_1: f(x)\neq 0\})=0$. But $\{x\in A_1: f(x)\neq 0\}=\{x\in X: f(x)> 0\}$. Hence $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)> 0\})=0$. Using analogous reasoning but replcing $f$ with $-f$ we get that $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)< 0\})=0$.

Hence $$\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\})=0.$$

Suppose that $f=u+iv$. Then $$\{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\}=\{x\in X: u(x)\neq 0\}\cup \{x\in X: v(x)\neq 0\}.$$
Since $f\in L^1(\mu)$ and $\int \limits_{X}fd\mu=\int \limits_{X}ud\mu+i\int \limits_{X}vd\mu$(by definition) and $\operatorname{Re}\int \limits_{X}fd\mu=\int \limits_{X}ud\mu$. Using above reasoning for real-valued functions we get that $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\})=0$,i.e. $f=0$ a.e. on $X$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Quick-note: complex-valued function does not take infinity as a value.

Comment: Yes you are right but what this remark ?

Comment: The remark is still correct, and indeed you can consider a function $f:X\to[0,\infty)$ to be $f:X\to[0,\infty]$. My note is just a bit technical.

Comment: @E.Girgin, 
but I think that my decision is generally true . What do you think ?

Comment: Just after the remark, you should've said $f1_{A_1}$ is a non-negative valued function. So, $\int_{A_1}f1_{A_1}d\mu=0$ implies $f1_{A_1}=0$ a.e. on $A_1$. You can't use the remark directly on $f$ as it is not non-negative valued.

Comment: the proof is correct other than the issues I mentioned.

Comment: @E.Girgin, Hmmm. But $A_1=\{x\in X; f(x)\geqslant 0\}$. Right? So $f$ is non-negative on $A_1$. I maybe i missunderstand smth?

Comment: @E.Girgin, By remark $f$ must be non-negative on whole $X$, right? So $f$ may not be, $f\chi_{A_1}$ is non-negative on whole $X$. Am I right?

Comment: Your argument is right, but you need to put that argument into the correct shape. The remark works for a non-negative function and a measurable set. When you say "$\int_{A_1}fd\mu=0$ implies $f=0$ a.e. on $A_1$" you are using the remark for $f$ and $A_1$, but, $f$ is not a non-negative function. Instead, you should use $f1_{A_1}$, where $1_{A_1}$ is the characteristic function of $A_1$, i.e. $1_{A_1}(x)=0$ if $x\notin A_1$ and $1_{A_1}(x)=1$ otherwise. When you say by remark we have "$\int_{A_1}f1_{A_1}d\mu=0$ implies $f1_{A_1}=0$ a.e. on $A_1$" you are using the remark in the correct form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40452/discussion-between-rfz-and-e-girgin).